# Python requests missing cookies after redirect

Tags: python-requests, session-cookies, forms-authentication, python-3.7

I am trying to replicate an authentication process in python.

It's a little bit tricky since after the first call, it issues a 302 redirect. So as you can see, I handle that in my code, extract the location and I do a second get at it to finally reach the correct url.

But the problem starts at: **responseSecondGet = session.get(redirect_URL,headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)**, after doing that the website responds with a Set-Cookie command that does not get saved in the session headers.

So at the end when I try to do the post, it is missing the cookie on the post request header.

Can anyone, please, help me find out what is wrong ? Below is my code and the full auth process that I captured using a proxy

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

headers = {
    'Host':'www.test-website.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False

responseFirstGet = session.get("https://www.test-website.com/members/login.php",headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)

if responseFirstGet.status_code == 302:
   redirect_URL = responseFirstGet.headers['Location']
   responseSecondGet = session.get(redirect_URL,headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)

encodedUrl = urllib.parse.quote('http://www.test-website.com/members/index.php',safe='')
encodedUrl = encodedUrl.replace('.','%2e')
encodedUrl = encodedUrl.replace('-','%2d')
encodedUrl = encodedUrl.lower()

headersAuth = {
    'Host':'ams.test-website.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'https://www.test-website.com',
    'Referer': redirect_URL,
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }


body = {
    'rlm':'RESTRICTED',
    'for': encodedUrl,
    'rmb': 'y',
    'uid': 'username',
    'pwd': 'password'
    }

postAuthentication = session.post("https://ams.test-website.com/auth.form", headers=headersAuth, data=body,allow_redirects=False)
```

---

**Here is the authentication process that I captured using BurpSuite**

**First Get/Response**

```
GET /members/login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.test-website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2019 11:09:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 425
Location: https://www.test-website.com/auth.form?Zmd2aktKVmhPNHNlOEphZHpQMnVJdHJWL2JsMGxtZmE4ZlR5TzQ4a1N0YWZSTVBhT28yQWkyVTE4ZlRXV3htRgpnelBjMER2VDFYUlhWZmRQRWg5ME5vN0thallXeWdlMWdZOVNWQzkxRkhmam9udEVHWHd1MHZJSDRKcXhZV0gvCnRZalM5Q3YxcU5RPQo=
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: pcar%5fUkVTVFJJQ1RFRA%3d%3d=; path=/; domain=.test-website.com; expires=Fri 16-Nov-2018 05:05:32 GMT
X-Cache-Dynamic: Dynamic
```

**Second Get/Response**

```
GET /auth.form?Zmd2aktKVmhPNHNlOEphZHpQMnVJdHJWL2JsMGxtZmE4ZlR5TzQ4a1N0YWZSTVBhT28yQWkyVTE4ZlRXV3htRgpnelBjMER2VDFYUlhWZmRQRWg5ME5vN0thallXeWdlMWdZOVNWQzkxRkhmam9udEVHWHd1MHZJSDRKcXhZV0gvCnRZalM5Q3YxcU5RPQo= HTTP/1.1
Host: www.test-website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2019 11:09:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: pcar%5fUkVTVFJJQ1RFRA%3d%3d=; path=/; domain=.test-website.com; expires=Fri 16-Nov-2018 05:05:33 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=1, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 16 Nov 2019 05:05:33 GMT
Content-Length: 14442
```

**Post Request/Response**

```
POST /auth.form HTTP/1.1
Host: ams.test-website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 147
Origin: https://www.test-website.com
Connection: close
Referer: https://www.test-website.com/auth.form?Zmd2aktKVmhPNHNlOEphZHpQMnVJdHJWL2JsMGxtZmE4ZlR5TzQ4a1N0YWZSTVBhT28yQWkyVTE4ZlRXV3htRgpnelBjMER2VDFYUlhWZmRQRWg5ME5vN0thallXeWdlMWdZOVNWQzkxRkhmam9udEVHWHd1MHZJSDRKcXhZV0gvCnRZalM5Q3YxcU5RPQo=
Cookie: pcah=Mi9VMGVmdGZMcHE2anZZYmZham4rTUlsU0huYzRYb0IK
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

rlm=RESTRICTED&for=http%253a%252f%252fwww%252etest%252dwebsite%252ecom%252fmembers%252findex%252ephp&rmb=y&uid=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2019 05:05:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Set-Cookie: pcar%5fUkVTVFJJQ1RFRA%3d%3d=cS90NW9XLzVVeVJrSGkzQkxxUzZNOTlnNWtxMStWOUxiM3JjSDBRZS84Zz0K; path=/; domain=.test-website.com; expires=Sat 16-Nov-2019 11:05:41 GMT
Location: http://www.test-website.com/members/index.php
Content-Length: 239
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Which version of the `requests` module are you using?

Comment: 2.22 latest version